# Parse a json without jQuery and add the value in HTML code

Tags: javascript, json

First of all: I do not want to use jQuery.

I would like to find a way to parse this type of json and add it text into the special tag:

```
{
    "datas": {
        "General": [
            {
                "id": "hotel_name",
                "value": "My Hotel name"
            },
            {
                "id": "hotel_description",
                "value": "Lorem ipsum dolor..."
            }
        ],
        "Photos": [
            {
                "id": "photo1",
                "value": "house.png"
            },
            {
                "id": "photo2",
                "value": "house.png"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

On a HTML I have special tag:

```
<mytag id="hotel_name"></mytag>
```

Must become:

```
<mytag id="hotel_name">My Hotel name</mytag>
```

I tried this:

```
function createElements(elements) {
    elements = JSON.parse(elements);

    elements.forEach(funciton (element) {
        var div = document.getElementById(element.id);
        div.innerHTML = element.text;
    });
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onload = createElements;
request.open("get", "datas.json", true);
request.send();
```

But it do not work like I wanted.

Do you have any cue ?

Thanks.

Comment: shouldnt that be `elements.datas.General.forEach(....)`? What I mean is, is it only the things under `General` you want to perform this actions for, or under `General` and `Photos` perhaps?

Comment: Depending the page it will be in `General` or/and `Photos`. In the json, the id will be always unique like is the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Note, `text` not appear as property of object within `datas.General` , `datas.Photos` arrays ; see `element.text` . Properties appear named `id` , `value` ; i.e.g., `element.id` , `element.value`.

To filter single property name, try

```
function createElements(elements) {
    if (elements.target.readyState === 4) {
    var elems = elements.target.response;
        var keys = Object.keys(elems.datas).filter(function(name) {
          return name === "General"
        });
    keys.forEach(function (element, i) {
        var el = elems.datas[element];
        el.forEach(function(key, i) {
          var div = document.getElementById(key.id);
          div.innerHTML = key.value;
        })
    });
    }
};

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();    
request.onload = createElements;
request.responseType = "json";
request.open("GET", "datas.json", true);
request.send();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k2f7b3mp/

---

To filter multiple property names, try

```
function createElements(elements) {
    if (elements.target.readyState === 4) {
    var elems = elements.target.response;
        var keys = Object.keys(elems.datas).filter(function(name) {
            return name === "General" || name === "Color"
        });
        console.log(keys, 1)
    keys.forEach(function (element, i) {
        var el = elems.datas[element];
        el.forEach(function(key, i) {
            console.log(key, i);
            if (document.getElementById(key.id)) {
              var div = document.getElementById(key.id);
              div.innerHTML = key.value;
            }
        })
    });
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b6n8q1d1/2/

Comment: Amazing! Just a question before accepting. If `General` and `Photos` are dynamics? For example, perhaps, I could have `Fruits` and `Colors`.

Comment: @poipoi Would `Fruits` , `Colors` contain same array, having same properties, values as `General` , `Photos` ?

Comment: Yes, the only on thing it could change is `General` or `Photos`. Sometimes I could have 1, 2, 3, ... properties.

Comment: If data structure of `datas` remained same , could try substituting `return name === "Fruits"` for `return name === "General"` ? If property names of `datas` was `1,2,3` _and_ structure remained same , could try ` return name === "1"` ? Though what would `3` contain ?

Comment: No I mean that I could have one case with a json with 1 or more properties. So for example, in the same json : `Fruits`, `General`, `Photos`, ...

Comment: But the structure of each property will remain the same.

Comment: Select the appropriate object which contained the desired properties , values ? That is, `Photos` _not_ utilized at piece described at OP - only `General` . Similarly, select property names within `.filter()` which contain the desired property names; containing values which will be appended to DOM elements . More than a single property could be returned from `.filter()` ; i.e.g., `return name === "Fruits" || name === "General"` .

Comment: @poipoi Not entirely certain what requirement would be within `.forEach` where more than a single property was returned from `.filter()` , whose values were appended to `DOM` ? Piece at OP appear to seek filter of _single_ item within returned data ?

Comment: @poipoi Can post example of additional properties , expected result at `.forEach` ?

Comment: Sometimes the sons could contains more than 2 properties (like in your jsfiddle.net). Mine, contains 3 properties http://jsfiddle.net/b6n8q1d1/1/.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:

```
elements.datas.General.forEach(function (element) {
    var div = document.getElementById(element.id);
    div.innerHTML = element.text;
});
```

You have to resolve each JSON property before you can loop the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<body>
<mytag id="hotel_name"></mytag>
<script>
    var xhr = null;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("hotel_name");
    function load() {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (xhr != null) {
            xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", callback, false);
            xhr.open("get", "datas.json", true);
            xhr.send();
        } else {
            alert("not support ajax!!");
        }
    }
    function callback() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                myDiv.innerHTML = data.datas.General[0].value;
            } else {
                myDiv.innerHTML = "<h2>" + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText + "</h2>";
            }
        }
    }
    load()
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Gave me `<h2>0: </h2>` instead of `<h2>My Hotel name</h2>`.

Comment: Did you put datas.json in the same folder?

Comment: I think it is cross domain issue, could you deploy these two file in localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access each property of the objects

```
elements.datas.General.forEach(function (element) {
var div = document.getElementById(element.id);
div.innerHTML = element.value;
});
```

Working demo :

```js
var myJSONtext = " {\"datas\": { \"General\": [ { \"id\": \"hotel_name\", \"value\": \"My Hotel name\" }, { \"id\": \"hotel_description\", \"value\": \"Lorem ipsum dolor...\" } ], \"Photos\": [ { \"id\": \"photo1\", \"value\": \"house.png\" }, { \"id\": \"photo2\", \"value\": \"house.png\" } ] }}";
var elements = JSON.parse(" {\"datas\": { \"General\": [ { \"id\": \"hotel_name\", \"value\": \"My Hotel name\" }, { \"id\": \"hotel_description\", \"value\": \"Lorem ipsum dolor...\" } ], \"Photos\": [ { \"id\": \"photo1\", \"value\": \"house.png\" }, { \"id\": \"photo2\", \"value\": \"house.png\" } ] }}");

elements.datas.General.forEach(function (element) {
    var div = document.getElementById(element.id);
    div.innerHTML = element.value;
});
```

```html
<div id="hotel_name"></div>
```

same demo on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wzu29pau/

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work if I put `<div id="hotel_description"></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

poipoi.
If you don't have a problems about getting JSON data, I think that It seems work for you.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(request.responstext);

    console.log(obj.datas.General[0].id);
    console.log(obj.datas.Photos[1].id);
```

JSON data type is similar to Array. And you should know about JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() method.